# How do you set a filter that uses regex via a community visualisation in looker-studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm writing a community visualisation for looker-studio that allows filtering by nodes in a tree. As part of this, I need my visualisation to apply a filter that uses regex to determine whether or not to exclude nodes.

Currently, by looking at the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/visualization/interactions-guide), it appears that the library provided by google for interfacing with looker only allows filters that use equality. I know that it is possible to create filters that use regex within looker itself, but is it currently possible to set regex based filters via a community visualisation? and if so, how?